# How can I create different info Windows for different Markers?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm currently developing an app for Android, using Google Maps API v2. I'm really new to android developing, even if I studied (and I'm still studying) Java at university.

I managed to create the map, and to add my personal markers to it. Each marker need its own Info Window, and this is the problem. I can only modify Title and Snippet, but in the box I need to put also different pictures for different marker.

Markers represent Libraries.

Example:
Marker 1:
name
services (different images for air conditioning, food, plugs and so on)
number of seats available

Name is not a problem: it's title. Seats as well is represented by the snippet. But the images are the problem: I can't find a way to show different images in different windows.

Here's the Java code for the Main Activity:

```java
package com.matteocunsolo.apposto;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

     class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter{

            private final View myContentsView;

            MyInfoWindowAdapter(){
                myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                TextView tvTitle = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.title));
                tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
                TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
                tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());   
                return myContentsView;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

     }

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            // Loading map
            initializeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initializeMap() {

        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
            if(googleMap != null) {
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            }
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(41.903021, 12.514744)).zoom(15).build();

            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            createMarkers();

            googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyInfoWindowAdapter());
            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }





    void createMarkers() {


        String name = "Biblioteca Alessandrina";
        double latitude = 41.903021;
        double longitude = 12.514744;
        Marker m = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(name).position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).snippet("250"));

        String name2 = "Biblioteca CIAO";
        double latitude2 = 41.906332;
        double longitude2 = 12.517669;
        Marker m2 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(name2 + "\n").position(new LatLng(latitude2, longitude2)).snippet("134"));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initializeMap();
    }

}
```

And here's the XML for the Info Window:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/title"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="30dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
           android:text="title"
           android:textSize="25dp"
           android:textStyle="bold" />

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="horizontal" >

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="23dp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
               android:text="Services:   "
               android:textSize="20dp" />

           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="20dp"
               android:layout_height="20dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
               android:adjustViewBounds="true"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="20dp"
               android:layout_height="20dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
               android:adjustViewBounds="true"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="20dp"
               android:layout_height="20dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
               android:adjustViewBounds="true"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="horizontal" >

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
               android:text="Seats:   "
               android:textSize="20dp" />
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/snippet"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
               android:textSize="20dp"
               android:text="150" />
       </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can only modify Title and Snippet, but in the box I need to put also different pictures for different marker.

Your `getInfoContents()` method can certainly change more than that.

> But the images are the problem: I can't find a way to show different images in different windows

Retrieve the `ImageView` using `findViewById()`, and set the image you want to use for it, in your `getInfoContents()` method. This is no different than how you are changing the `TextView` widgets.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this way and actually I managed to fix this problem. Partly, though. In fact I tried this with two markers, one of them shows 2 images and the other one shows 3. It worked but if I click on the marker with 2 pics I sede the correct 2. Bit if I click firstly on the marker with 3 pics and then on the one with two, I still see the 3 of the other marker.